# can´t access specific element of my array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a problem with my react app.The navbar worked correctly before the ItemDetailContainer, and i want to show in the DOM an specific product. When adding the ItemDetailContainer to app.js, the page doesn't show anything (including the navbar) . Here's my code:

ItemDetailContainer.jsx:

```
const {products} = require('../utils/data');

const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
    const [arrayList, SetArrayList] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        customFetch(2000, products[0])
            .then(result => SetArrayList(result))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <ItemDetail products={arrayList}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

here's my array in data.js that i want to access:

```
const products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: "https://baltimore.com.ar/img/articulos/4188.png",
        title: "Vino Abras Malbec 750cc",
        price: 2.500,
        stock: 8,
        initial: 1
    }
```

ItemDetail.jsx:

```
const ItemDetail = ({product}) => {
    return(
        <>
        {product.image}
        {product.title}
        </>
    )
}
```

CustomFetch.js:

```
let is_ok = true

let customFetch = (time, array) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (is_ok) {
                resolve(array)
            } else {
                reject("error")
            }
        }, time)
    })
}
```

and my app.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <ItemDetailContainer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've done all the imports and exports, but I dont' know what's the problem.

Comment: What is exactly the error you are getting? Update pls post

Comment: @antokhio I've updated it, let me know if there's something unclear

Comment: In ItemDetail you destructure your props,and you try to get a "product" value,but in <ItemDetail products={arrayList}/> you pass it as "products". Try <ItemDetail product={arrayList}/> and see how it goes

Comment: @Vaggelis just done it but it still doesn't show me anything

Comment: @isherwood the syntax of ({product}) is to show specific things in the dom, not all the things like the stock or initial

Comment: @MaximilianoRodriguez You sure ?  https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-https-rq6hjv

Comment: What does `customFetch` produce as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing a **`product`** prop in  `<ItemDetail product={arrayList}/>` within **`ItemDetailContainer`** make sure you destructure your props correctly in `ItemDetail` component,like so  :

```
const ItemDetail = ({product}) => {
  return(
      <>
      {product.image}
      {product.title}
      </>
  )
}
```

Which is basically like this :

```
const ItemDetail = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.product.image}
      {props.product.title}
    </>
  );
};
```

[check it out in code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vaggelis-example-for-maximiliano-rodriguez-from-s-o-https-stackoverflow-com-q-73779069-14718856-forked-yyrqtp?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Just done it like you did but it doesn't show me anything. I don't know why it works in yours but in mine not

Comment: How do you export your products from utils/data ? check out the sandbox again (new link) i edited it like its supposed to be exported,based on your code

Comment: thank you so much, it was all about the export const products but I didn't notice it

Comment: Not "All" about the exporting,you had also an error in passing the prop into the child component. cheers man keep it going !